# React Native 100% Height Page

Tags: android, react-native

REACT NATIVE

Is it possible to create a page on my app that covers the screen untill the navigation bar of the most modern phones? Like the page has enough height to wrap phones' bottom navigation bar like on my prototype?

Example in the image:

[My Prototype](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xkUiQ.png)

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is, if you want your page to occupy the whole screen just do:

```
<View style={{ height: '100%', width: '100%' }}>

   // YOUR CONTENT

</View>
```

Now, if you want to hide the android navigation bar you can do:

```
  const visibility = NavigationBar.useVisibility()

  async function setBar() {

    await NavigationBar.setBehaviorAsync('overlay-swipe')

    await NavigationBar.setVisibilityAsync('hidden')
  }

  useEffect(() => {

    setBar()
  }, []);
```

Since I don't own an iPhone I wouldn't know how to hide the ios navigation bar, but for android that is the solution.
I hope this helps!